# JS: I'm not getting the scope

Tags: javascript, scope, couchdb

I'm trying to modify CouchDB's JS API to work asynchronous, but there is an error I cannot solve:

Please find my JS API find [at pastebin](http://pastebin.com/2ns6HfDB).
If I call `(new CouchDB("dbname")).allDocs(function(result) {console.log(result)})` (line 193) I get an error because the okCallback function is not defined in the callback function.

I don't know why; it should be defined in this scope..

Any hints are very welcome!

Cheers,
Manuel

Comment: Manuel, what is the status of this issue? Looks like VoteyDisciple's answer fixed it, correct?

Answer (score 1):

`designDocs` takes `okCallback` as a parameter. You are not passing a parameter when you call the function. Hence, the value is undefined.

Comment: I'm so bloody stupid.
Sorry, my example is wrong.
I tried this call instead `(new CouchDB("dbname")).allDocs(function(result) {console.debug(result)});`